# changing position of sidebar

Tags: html, css, sidebar

```css
.page-wrapper {
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

.middle-wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
}

.main-page-content {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0;
}

.title1 {
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

p {
  margin: 1rem 0 2rem;
}


.callout {
  background: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.395);
  border-radius: var(--elem-radius);
  box-shadow: rgb(95, 95, 95);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.boxed {
  border: 1px solid rgb(78, 78, 78) ;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 37em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

}

.textinrect {
  word-spacing: 100px;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  max-width: 200px;
}


.list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.sidebar-heading {
  color: Black;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: tahoma;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  
}

.subject-header {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.749);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: tahoma;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}


.subject {
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.toggle {
margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.sub-topic {
  color: black;
}

.toggle1 {
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.toggle0 {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 1.5em ;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fortest.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="page-wrapper">
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="middle-wrapper">
    <article class="main-page-content">
      <h2 class="title1">How to create an HTML website</h2>
      <div class="section1">
        <p>1. Nav Bar</p>
        <div class="callout">
          <div class="boxed">
            <div class="textinrect">
              Yourwebsitename home about page3
            </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
  <aside class="sidebar">
    <nav class="sidebar-inner">
      <p class="sidebar-heading">Subjects</p>
      <div>

        <ol class="list">
          <li class="subject">
            <a href="#">
              <h5 class="subject-header">Subject1</h5>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="toggle"> 
            <details>
              <summary>
              All the school sunjects
              </summary>

              <ol class="toggle0">
                <li class="toggle1">
                  <a class="sub-topic" href="#">The molecular mass and power</a>
                </li>

                <li class="toggle1">
                  <a class="sub-topic" href="#">the molecular mass and power</a>
                </li>
              </ol>
            </details>
          </li>

          <li class="toggle"> 
            <details>
              <summary>
              Not all school subjects
            </summary>
            </details>
          </li>
        </ol>

      </div>
    </nav>
  </aside>


</div>

 
</body>
</html>
```

My goal is that the sidebar stays on the side at the very beginning of the document on the left side of the main text. For some reason it says down below the main section. I know this is a matter of position but I can not find the correct position. I would deeply appreciate any answer that you may give.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
#sidebar {
float: left;
width: 208px;
padding-top: 30px;
background-color:#D2D2D2;
margin-left:initial;
/*position: fixed;*/ //remove it
}

#content {
float: left; // change right to left
width: 564px;
padding-top: 30px;
}
```